# UPDATED -Email activity fails to send to contacts that are entering into the journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

The use case is:

-Contacts are entering into the journey when an event occurs in Sales Cloud, with their email address correctly.

[image: AUDIENCE]

-When contacts come to email activity, it seems that they have received the email.

-When we see the tracking, we can see that emails are not sending to all contacts that are entering.
[image: EMAIL ACTIVITY]

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

UPDATED:

@Markus: It seems ok, here there is the email activity history of today for this journey:
[image: Email History]

@Eliot: the subscriber are active in all subs list, and the email was validated with the synch sendable data extension. I have tested this journey every time, and every 10 first sends works, but after that, do not send more.

Note: There were some ampscript rules were trying to render empty fields (such as ContentBlocksbyID rendering the name in the subject). I am going to avoid that in order to check if it is works finally.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Check the Journey History for failed email send activities and please update your question to include these messages. This will help providing the correct answer as there are multiple reasons why a send fails.

Comment: Have any of these Subscribers unsubscribed? Are they using emails that are failing by the list validator? For example, they are using invalid emails or role based email addresses (sales@, admin@, help@, etc). As Markus points out, the History might give you some clues.

Comment: Question updated @MarkusSlabina

Comment: It was solved adding a wait activity after executing the trigger event.